# Префиксы css для flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Вот код css

```
body{
-webkit-display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
}
```

С помощью такого кода страница становиться более адаптивной, все элементы появляются в центре страницы что мне и нужно. Только когда я прописываю префикс `-webkit-` или другие префиксы браузеров к `display: flex` То код перестает работать и все элементы которые были в центре передвигаются назад к левой стороне страницы. Не понимаю в чём проблема, или я префикс не так пишу?

Comment: правильно будет display: -webkit-flex; а вообще display: flex давно поддерживается в браузерах на базе Webkit безо всяких префиксов: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого свойства нет в браузере, если используете `display: -webkit-flex`, то всё у Вас заработает.
Если Вы используете `LESS` к примеру, то можете создать миксин такого вида и использовать его для своих нужд:

```
.flex-display(@display: flex) {
    display: ~"-webkit-@{display}";
    display: ~"-ms-@{display}box"; // IE10 uses -ms-flexbox
    display: ~"-ms-@{display}"; // IE11
    display: @display;
}
```